# Include unique line of best fit and r2 values for multiple plots in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics

I have one figure with multiple scatterplots on it and when I try to include a line of best fit, it gives me the same line for each of the figures. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

But I want the line to be unique to the datapoints in each plot.

This is the code I have so far. I won't include the code for inputting the data because it is a lot, and I'm pretty sure the problem is within the for-loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(len(uniq)):
    plt.subplot(6,6,i+1)
    indx = dat['year'] == uniq[i]
    plt.scatter(x[indx], y[indx], s=15, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(i), label=uniq[i])
    m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    plt.plot(x, m*x + b, '-')
```

### Edit to question:

How can I also print the r2 value for the lines of best fit? So far, I have:

```
from scipy import stats
def rsquared(x, y):
     """ Return R^2 where x and y are array-like."""
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
    return r_value**2

for i in range(len(uniq)):
    plt.subplot(6,6,i+1)
    indx = dat['year'] == uniq[i]
    plt.scatter(x[indx], y[indx], s=15, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(i), label=uniq[i])
    plt.legend(prop={'size':5})
    plt.xticks(size = 10)
    plt.yticks(size = 10)
    m, b = np.polyfit(x[indx], y[indx], 1)
    plt.plot(x, m*x + b, '-')
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x[indx], y[indx])
    print("r-squared:", r_value**2)
```

It would also be great if I could print the r2 value next to the lines of best fit.

Comment: `m, b = np.polyfit(x[indx], y[indx], 1)`

Comment: Thank you! I knew that was easy @gereleth

Comment: @gereleth I am updating the question in case you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by @gereleth

```
for i in range(len(uniq)):
    plt.subplot(6,6,i+1)
    indx = dat['year'] == uniq[i]
    plt.scatter(x[indx], y[indx], s=15, color=scalarMap.to_rgba(i), label=uniq[i])
    plt.legend(prop={'size':5})
    plt.xticks(size = 10)
    plt.yticks(size = 10)
    m, b = np.polyfit(x[indx], y[indx], 1)
    plt.plot(x, m*x + b, '-')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the new edit, to annotate the plot, simply use `matplotlib`'s [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html):

```
plt.annotate('Corr. coef = %.3f' % r_value**2, (0.8, 0.2), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='center', size=10)
```

[image: annotated graph]